# Android MediaMetaData image for Cast Dialog

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Noticing something strange with the cast dialog. Using the MediaInfo.Builder to prepare MediaInfo for a call to RemoteMediaClient.load(mediainfo), if the same image URL is used for MediaMetaData.addImage this time as was used in the prior call the image does not show up in the dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the console log on the Chromecast to see if there are any issues there? You may refer with this [related issue](https://github.com/videostream/cordova-chromecast/issues/21).

Comment: Don't see anything on the log but I've confirmed the same behaviour using the CastVideos-android sample app. In the buildMediaInfo() function just replace the selectedmedia.getImage calls with a constant image url. The image appears in the cast dialog the first time. On subsequent uses the image is blank. https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android .. look in VideoProvider.java

Comment: sorry I mispoke  ... look in LocalPlayerActivity.loadRemoteMedia(). At the end there's the line remoteMediaClient.load(mSelectedMedia, autoPlay, position); To show the problem I rebuilt mSelectedMedia to fix the image URL to be the same every time.

Comment: Logged issue with the sdk https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1142&sort=-id

Comment: I also provided additional info about this problem on issue tracker, they now accepted it as a bug.

Comment: Just saw that - thanks