# Pause button not working in Android cast dialog

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

The pause button in the Cast Dialog doesn't seem to be working. I noticed the same issue with the CastVideos-android sample app. Has anyone worked around this?

Comment: Can you add some codes and logs of the issue encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exactly same issue, I worked around by making classess extending MediaRouteDialogFactory, MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment, and MediaRouteControllerDialog.

---

```
public class MyMediaRouteDialogFactory extends MediaRouteDialogFactory {
        @NonNull @Override
        public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
           return new MyMediaControllerDialogFragment();
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class MyMediaControllerDialogFragment extends MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment {
    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new MyMediaRouteControllerDialog(context);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyMediaRouteControllerDialog extends MediaRouteControllerDialog {
    public MyMediaRouteControllerDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyMediaRouteControllerDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.getAttributes().dimAmount = 0.5f;
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        }

        View playPause = findById(this, R.id.mr_control_play_pause);
        if (playPause != null && playPause instanceof ImageView && getOwnerActivity() != null) {
            UIMediaController mediaController = new UIMediaController(getOwnerActivity());
            mediaController.bindImageViewToPlayPauseToggle((ImageView) playPause, mPlayArrowDrawable, mPauseDrawable, mStopDrawable, null, false);
        }
    }
```

}

---

```
{
    // On initializing MediaRouteButton
    ((MediaRouteButton) mCastButton).setDialogFactory(new MyMediaRouteDialogFactory());
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getActivity(), mCastButton);
}
```

---

In short, I bound play/pause button to UIMediaController.

Comment: Jaewoo, Thanks for your detailed response. The only place I'm stuck is on the last part. In my app the cast button is defined in an actionbar menu so I'm calling CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), m, R.id.item_mediaroute) where m is the menu inflated in the AppCompatActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu call. Not sure how to setDialogFactory with my usage..

Comment: Trick is to get the MediaRouteActionProvider by calling (MediaRouteActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(MenuItem) and then calling setDialogFactory on that

Comment: So now the pause button sends a message to the receiver which in turn calls my instance of cast.receiver.media.Player.pause() in javascript. Perfect. Again on the receiver side I change the state of the Player from "PLAYING" to "PAUSED" and return that string in cast.receiver.media.Player.getState(). Doing this causes pause image in the sender cast dialog to change to the play image. Progress! However, pressing the play button in the cast dialog does nothing.... I will try this out on the CastVideos-android sample app

Comment: Implementing Jaewoo's answer into the CastVideos-android sample app fixed the cast dialog play/pause functionality. I still have my problem with pause working but play not but I think that's because I have a custom receiver and need to research the protocol further.

Comment: To be more exact and specific, the sample app on github itself works well (it uses support library 23.4.0 and play services 9.4.0), but updating support library and google play service library up-to-date makes this issue. Currently, Support library 25.2.0 and play services 10.2.0 are latest versions.

Comment: Great observation - may also explain this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348635/android-mediametadata-image-for-cast-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Please update your google play services.Faced same issue when using 9.8.0. Updated to 10.2.1, it got resolved.